# How do I convert an index to an Excel-like column number in a functional way?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, spreadsheet, numeric

I'd like to write a function that generates the corresponding column name for a specific number, for example A for 1 or AA for 127. I know this has been answered quite a lot already, but I'd like to do it in a functional way.

Sure, you should be able to convert the existing (imperative) answers pretty easily, but I find myself getting stuck every time I try to.

Any good ideas / functional implementations?

Comment: Since there's not much effort in the question, here's an "answer" without much effort ;) `var toLetterCode=i=>(i.toString(26).split("").map((i26,i,is)=>"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[parseInt(i26,26)-(i===0&&is.length>1?1:0)]).join(""));`

Answer (score -1):

Here's a working implementation.

```js
var letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];

function toLetter(number) {

  if (!number || number <= 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  var code = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(number / 26); i++) {
    code += letters[i];
  }
  code += letters[(number % 26) - 1];
  
  return code;
}

console.log(toLetter(27)); // returns AA;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't a functional approach. Functional, meaning there are no mutable variables and no loops (while/for) changing those variables.